# Is there better way to swallow StopIteration exception generated by yield in python?

Tags: python, yield, yield-keyword

Now I plan to learn more about `yield` in python. And I found some codes about yield, which implemented the algorithm [`Reservoir Sampling`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling) as following:

```
def RandomSelect(knum, rand=None):
    ''' (int, func) -> list

    Reservoir Sampling implementation
    '''
    selection = None
    k_elems_list = []
    count = 0

    if rand is None:
        rand = Random()

    while True:
        item = yield selection
        if len(k_elems_list) < knum:
            k_elems_list.append(item)
        else:
            # Randomly replace elements in the reservoir with a decreasing probability
            r = rand.randint(0, count)
            if r < knum:
                k_elems_list[r] = item
        count += 1
    print k_elems_list
```

In order to break the `while` loop, I just add some codes after `item = yield selection`

```
        if item == -1: # reach to the end of data, just break
            break
```

**Question 1**, Is there any better way to break out the while loop?

To call the function `RandomSelect`,

```
myList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,-1]
cr = RandomSelect(3);
cr.next() # advance to the yield statement, otherwise I can't call send
try:
    for val in myList:
        cr.send(val)
except StopIteration:
    pass
finally:
    del cr
```

I have to catch the `StopIteration` exception explicitly.

**Question 2**, is there any better way to swallow the `StopIteration` in the codes?

Comment: Is there a (good) reason `RandomSelect` is written as a coroutine? Why can't it just get an iterable over the values (`myList` in your example) as parameter, loop over it, and `yield` the selections without expecting feedback via `send`?

Comment: @delnan, I just want to know how to handle it if `yield` is used in these codes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a slightly cleaner way to accomplish what is being done — which addresses both your questions — would be to explicitly close the generator by calling its`close()`method to terminate it and break out of the loop. Doing so also means a`StopIteration`doesn't need to be "swallowed". Another benefit is it's no longer necessary to add the `-1` sentinel value at the end of the list.

```
def RandomSelect(knum, rand=None):
    ''' (int, func) -> list

    Reservoir Sampling implementation
    '''
    selection = None
    k_elems_list = []
    count = 0
    if rand is None:
        rand = Random()   

    while True:
        try:
            item = yield selection
        except GeneratorExit:
            break
        if len(k_elems_list) < knum:
            k_elems_list.append(item)
        else:
            # Randomly replace elements in the reservoir with a decreasing probability
            r = rand.randint(0, count)
            if r < knum:
                k_elems_list[r] = item
        count += 1
    print k_elems_list

myList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
cr = RandomSelect(3)
cr.next() # advance to the yield statement, otherwise I can't call send
for val in myList:
    cr.send(val)
cr.close()    
del cr
```

A minor additional enhancement (about something you didn't ask about) would be to make it so it wasn't necessary to manually advance to the`yield`statement before calling`send()`. A good way to accomplish that would be with a decorator function similar to the one named`consumer()`David Beazley described in his *Generator Tricks
For Systems Programmers* [presentation](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/Generators.pdf) at PyCon 2008:

```
def coroutine(func):
    """ Decorator that takes care of starting a coroutine automatically. """
    def start(*args, **kwargs):
        cr = func(*args, **kwargs)
        cr.next()
        return cr
    return start

@coroutine
def RandomSelect(knum, rand=None):
          .
          .
          .
    print k_elems_list

myList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
cr = RandomSelect(3)
#cr.next() # NO LONGER NECESSARY
for val in myList:
    cr.send(val)
cr.close()    
del cr
```